# Storing a defined array with booleans in Larvel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I may not have the correct vernacular to ask this question - but I'm going to go ahead and try.

I have a pre-determined array `['Device1', 'Device2', 'Device3', 'Device4']` - these options won't change (unless I manually add another option). I need a way to store these in SQL via Laravel *with* a boolean attached.

My questions are: what SQL type should they be, I was thinking possibly JSON? And how do I define this via a controller in Laravel while making the booleans easily editable via my front end?

This project is Laravel 5.7 and the DB is MySql 5.7.26

Comment: Do you want to store data like this: `['Device1' => true, 'Device2' => false, ...]`?

Comment: You can save them as an array or JSON both should be fine, and laravel can do the casting automatiacally for you, take a look at this part of the documentation
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting

Comment: @Menawer I think that's **exactly** what I was looking for. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

it'll be good if you provide some more information but I'll answer with my own consideration

it's better to normalize database with a table like `devices` and put your data in this table

then control it with boolean.

(this answer should be comment but I can't comment)